# How to stop blender from slowing down web browser while in cycles viewport?

Tags: performance

I'm trying to follow tutorials, but whenever I have the blender window active, youtube slows down to a point where the audio starts studdering and the video stops updating. I know blender generally needs all the power it can get, but how can I make it so I can still watch videos while doing it?

Comment: Hi :). Is your cycles viewport set to high samples? That would explain the high GPU usage...

Comment: its just set to 32

Comment: well, as long as it computes the viewport, your GPU/CPU will be somewhat occupied. You can limit the max number of CPU cores, or disable GPU from rendering.